# What is a good antonym for 'one track thinking'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

the meaning to be conveyed is the quality of

> being able to explore a situation with multiple viewpoints instead of just stuck with one way of exploring the problem

What word (or a few words) will convey this idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just as a quick answer 'open minded' comes to mind.

Answer (score 7):

*lateral thinking* seems like the most obvious choice to me...

Comment: I completely agree! As I recall, when [Edward de Bono] popularised the term, he actually intended it to be understood as meaning one should *strike out laterally* (ie - in a different "plane") rather than follow established "one-dimensional" ways of thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Able to think outside of the box, broadminded.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that pops into my head is ***dynamic***. You could describe someone as a dynamic problem-solver, a dynamic thinker, etc.

You might also describe such a person as *perspicacious*, *perceptive* or *judicious*.

A *multitasker* is someone who can work on many things at once; in some contexts, that may be the word you're looking for.

If you're looking for an idiom to describe this person, you might say she *keeps all the balls in the air* or *fires on all cylinders*.

Answer (score 1):

"Broad perspective". Broad being the counterpoint to both "one" and "track" and perspective adding flexibility to the subject of "thinking"

Answer (score -1):

If the subject is a [finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine), then *[nondeterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite-state_machine)* is the proper word.  But when speaking of people, it won't be what you want.  For that case, [insightful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insightful) should be mentioned as absent from the wondrous answers given so far.